# Create dynamic variables and assign values to it

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create variables with dynamic name and assign to it some values

i have a config array and for each of the value i need a corresponding variable created to which i can assign a new instance of a function

```
var beta = ["a","b","c"];

for (var i=0 ; i<beta.length, i++){
   // do something
}
```

it would result in creation of the 3 variables

```
var valueA = new Var.func(a);
var valueB = new Var.func(b);
var valueC = new Var.func(c);
```

Comment: You can keep the values in an array instead of trying to create different variables. Or may be JSON object

Comment: Why do you want to create these variables? Please specify your use-case appropriately.

Comment: @31piy so that i can access them later on such as valueA.doSomething() or valueB.doSomething()